# Porque me sale ESTE ERROR que tengo un campo ambiguo ?

Tags: php, mysql

ESTE ES LA CONSULTA:

```
select asignaturas.materias, estudiantes.id_estudiantes, nombres,apellidos,
calificaciones.id_calificaciones,n1,n2,promedio 
from asignaturas,estudiantes,calificaciones where id_calificaciones='$idcaliurl';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque hay al menos un campo que se repite en más de una tabla, por lo que debes indicar a qué tabla pertenece el campo. Viendo la consulta, creo que el problema está aquí: `where id_calificaciones`, debes indicar a qué tabla pertenece `id_calificaciones` supongo que es a la tabla `calificaciones`, por tanto, se debería corregir si pones esto: **`where calificaciones.id_calificaciones`**

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda ya se ejecuto la consulta correctamente!!

Comment: Xavier, para futuras preguntas, evita poner palabras como `URGENTE`, o `AYUDA` o cosas de ese tipo. Por favor, [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/136188/edit) quitando del título la palabra `URGENTE`. Gracias.

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta.. Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque hay al menos un campo que se repite en más de una tabla, por lo que debes indicar a qué tabla pertenece el campo. Viendo la consulta, creo que el problema está aquí: `where id_calificaciones`, debes indicar a qué tabla pertenece `id_calificaciones` supongo que es a la tabla `calificaciones`, por tanto, se debería corregir si pones esto: `where calificaciones.id_calificaciones`.

También, para evitar futuros errores de ese tipo, acostumbre indicar siempre a qué tabla pertenece cada columna, aún cuando no haya posibilidad de que se repitan. En ese sentido, también sería bueno que indiques a qué tabla pertenecen las columnas `nombres`, `apellidos`, `n1`, y `n2`. Es algo opcional, pero yo suelo por costumbre poner el nombre de la tabla en las consultas en las que intervienen varias tablas.

Para no hacer la consulta muy larga, una costumbre es poner un alias compuesto de una letra o dos que representen a cada tabla. Por ejemplo, aquí damos el alias `a` para `asignaturas`, `e` para `estudiantes` y `c` para `calificaciones`.

Por ejemplo... aquí he *supuesto*  que las columnas `n1, n2, promedio` pertenecen a la tabla `calificaciones`, si no es así las cambias por su tabla correspondiente:

```
SELECT  
    a.materias, 
    e.id_estudiantes, 
    e.nombres,
    e.apellidos,
    c.id_calificaciones,
    c.n1,
    c.n2,
    c.promedio 
FROM 
    asignaturas a,
    estudiantes e, 
    calificaciones c 
WHERE c.id_calificaciones='$idcaliurl';
```

> **NOTA IMPORTANTE SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:**    Al ver esta parte de la consulta: `WHERE c.id_calificaciones='$idcaliurl'` se aprecia un grave
>   problema de seguridad. El hecho de pasar el valor `$idcaliurl`
>   directamente en la consulta, facilita la inyección de código malicioso
>   en tu programa. Deberías implementar el uso de consultas preparadas.